# How can I make my relative macro run on every 3rd row?

Tags: loops, excel, vba

Thanks for having a look.

All advice is welcome I'm a novice.

I've made a very long (and inefficient macro to move data around.)

It works correctly moving three columns into 3 rows several times across. Problem is I need it to apply to every 4th row running down about 1000 rows.

I think I am looking for a loop.. Not entirely sure. Would also appreciate a way of refering back so I don't need to repeat it agian and again as it is slowing things down.

```html
Sub FullMacro()


'Copy info over
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Cells.Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        
' Deletes Top Row
    Rows("1:35").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        
 ' InsertColumns Macro
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Columns("z:z").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Columns("AX:AX").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Columns("BA:BA").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Columns("BE:BE").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Columns("BG:BG").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    
'This moves the titles to a single long row

    Range("A2").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=Range("B1")
    Range("A3").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=Range("C1")
    Range("D2").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=Range("E1")
    Range("D3").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=Range("F1")
    Range("K2").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=Range("L1")
    Range("K3").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=Range("M1")
    Range("R3").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=Range("T1")
    Range("T1").Select
    Range("Y2").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=Range("Z1")
    Range("Y3").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=Range("AA1")
    Range("AB2").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=Range("AC1")
    Range("AB3").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=Range("AD1")
    Range("AJ2").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=Range("AK1")
    Range("AJ3").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=Range("AL1")
    Range("AM2").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=Range("AN1")
    Range("AM3").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=Range("AO1")
    Range("AO1").Select
    Range("AS2").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=Range("AT1")
    Range("AS3").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=Range("AU1")
    Range("AW2").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=Range("AX1")
    Range("AW3").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=Range("AY1")
    Range("AZ2").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=Range("BA1")
    Range("AZ3").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=Range("BB1")
    Range("BD2").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=Range("BE1")
    Range("BF2").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=Range("BG1")
    Range("BG1").Select
    
' Deletes the colums we don't need
    
    Columns("H:J").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("L:N").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("M:M").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("N:Q").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("T:X").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("Z:AB").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("AC:AC").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
           
' Deletes the rows which used to have the titles in them
    Rows("2:3").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Range("A1").Select
           
End Sub


Sub Mover()

'Moves the actual contents into the single row formatt

    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1).Range("A1")
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 2).Range("A1")
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 3).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1).Range("A1")
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 2).Range("A1")
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 4).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1).Range("A1")
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 2).Range("A1")
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 1).Range("A1")
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 2).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1).Range("A1")
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 2).Range("A1")
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 3).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1).Range("A1")
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 2).Range("A1")
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 3).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1).Range("A1")
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 2).Range("A1")
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 3).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1).Range("A1")
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 2).Range("A1")
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 3).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1).Range("A1")
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 2).Range("A1")
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 3).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1).Range("A1")
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 2).Range("A1")
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 3).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1).Range("A1")
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 2).Range("A1")
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 4).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1).Range("A1")
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1).Range("A1")
  
End Sub

'At the moment I have to repeat downwards by selecting a new active cell and running again. This is what I want to fix. 

    Sub looping()
    Range("A5").Select
    
    ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1).Range("A1")
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 2).Range("A1")
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 3).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1).Range("A1")
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 2).Range("A1")
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 4).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1).Range("A1")
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 2).Range("A1")
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 1).Range("A1")
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 2).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1).Range("A1")
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 2).Range("A1")
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 3).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1).Range("A1")
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 2).Range("A1")
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 3).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1).Range("A1")
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 2).Range("A1")
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 3).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1).Range("A1")
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 2).Range("A1")
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 3).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1).Range("A1")
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 2).Range("A1")
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 3).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1).Range("A1")
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 2).Range("A1")
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 3).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1).Range("A1")
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 2).Range("A1")
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 4).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1).Range("A1")
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1).Range("A1")
```

Answer (score 0):

I lose track of whats going on in your code pretty quickly so am quite sure that I do not understand the full extent of your issue? I know it should be in comment, but I do not have sufficient rep.

I assume that every fourth row is due to the moving columns into rows? if so you can reverse the order and start from the bottom column and move up. for the sake of example I to move it into a new sheet, but that can be quickly fixed:

```
Sub ColumnsToRow()

    Set oldWs = ActiveSheet


    'Assuming you want to start in the active selected cell, if it is always a fixed starting point then this should be updated
    'Row and Column index of activecell
    vcol = ActiveCell.Column
    vRow = ActiveCell.Row

    'get the last row in the selected column
    maxLastRow = oldWs.UsedRange.Rows.Count '~~> the last row index can not be higher that max row index in the sheet
    Set veryLastIndex = oldWs.Range(oldWs.Cells(maxLastRow + 1, vcol), oldWs.Cells(maxLastRow + 1, vcol)) '~~> sets the range object to the cell indexed one higher than the max row index

    lastRowInColumn = veryLastIndex.End(xlUp).Row '~~> go up from the veryLastIndex

    Set newWs = Worksheets.Add

    For i = lastRowInColumn To vRow Step -1

        'insert two rows below
        newWs.Cells(i, vcol).Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
        newWs.Cells(i, vcol).Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
            'move the cells into the newly created rows
            For j = 0 To 2
                oldWs.Cells(i, vcol + j).Copy Destination:=newWs.Cells(i + j, vcol)
            Next        
    Next

End Sub
```

If you could add a bit more description and perhaps a screenshot of before -> after it would be great.